# Htaccess not read

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2.2

I've got a problem with my .htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Acces protege"
AuthUserFile "/home/sites/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

IMO, the file .htaccess is not read as I tried to write with syntax error.
And nothing happened while I access to the page.

I've changed the conf file of Apache : apache2.conf.

Instead of

```
AllowOverride None
```

I've put

```
Allow Override All
```

Then

```
service apache2 restart
```

Yet no authentification activated.

Comment: In apache2.conf, Is the DocumentRoot pointing to /home/sites ?

Comment: apache2.conf has a DocumentRoot parameter, what is the value ?

Comment: <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Comment: @adesc2,  maalls ask you about DocumentRoot parameter in apache2.conf. The fact that AuthUserFile requires full path on server to file.

Comment: There is no DocumentRoot set yet for this site. We are not working with a domain name but with a IP address for now. After we will buy one. Should I give you the DocumentRoot of site-availaible/default but I've no more default file ...

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Acces protege"
AuthUserFile "/home/sites/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Change the require keyword to Require